# What is the name of this anime movie set in the 1960 with an alternative history plot?

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction, anime

Okay, I remember seeing this movie on the **TV** in **some channel** back in **2000** on a Saturday night. The anime movie is basically set somewhere during **60's**. But, it has an **alternative history plot** than our real world history. In this movie it is revealed that the Space Race was used as a cover up by both the US and the Soviets military for the deployment of their military forces into space. It is also revealed that sometime during the mid 50's a meteor crashed on earth. And this meteor contained a "liquid-metal" or something like that, which enabled both the US and Soviets to secretly build highly advance vehicles with amazing properties. One of the prime example being showcased in the movie is using the "liqud-metal" to build Hover Tanks. It is also revealed that all of this is kept a secret from the public(both in the US and Russia).

The main story starts on the Moon, with the American forces just recently (about 2.5 weeks) landing on the dark side of the moon. The movie follows the view point of an American Soldier named Collins and his platoon. Unfortunately, the American forces are forced off the Moon due to a surprise assault from the Soviets which results in the destruction of their main base. They then relocate to Mars, but find the Soviets are already there. Both sides here then locate alien artifacts, and the Americans also find a factory. The long-dead alien race that created the "liquid-metal" is also identified as the Cthonians, who inhabited a planet that is now the asteroid belt between Mars and Jupiter. It is found out that they visited Earth on several occasions, thus influencing Greek mythology. The Americans also learn of an ultimate weapon called the "Chimera" and head to Venus to learn more about it. Another Cthonian relic is recovered there, which also points them to Jupiter's moon Io. The Americans finds a third relic there, but this is stolen by a scientist defecting to the Soviets.

The Main Protagonist and his platoon are then deployed in Europa and are ordered to steal a Soviet fighter craft and tap into their communications network. The main protagonist and his platoon manage to quickly take care off the small Soviet Outpost in Europa and are able to successfully tap into the Soviets Communication Network. Doing so also reveals to the Americans the Soviets  main base which is located on Saturn's moon, Titan. The Main Protagonist and his Platoon is then Ordered to Hold Back and clean up Europa, while the  Main/Special Assault Forces is sent to Titan to destroy the Soviets Main Base. But the Main Protagonist and his platoon later learn that the Main Assault was a complete Disaster and that almost all of their Main Assault Force was annihilated. So, the Main Protagonist and his platoon are then sent out to Titan to rescue some of their surviving soldiers. It is here they learn that the Soviets were able to recreate the ultimate weapon  'Chimeras' by infusing the materials found from the relics and also the "liquid-Metal", into the blood of some of their Soldiers.

I think sometime later the 'Chimeras' become self aware and realize that the sole purpose of their existence is to destroy all life in the Universe. So, they quickly turn on their creator i.e the Soviets. Although the Soviets suffer a large blow to their forces they are able to escape from complete annihilation. Also, the 'Chimeras' after turning on their Creators they mysteriously blast off from Titan. The Soviets then quickly realizing their mistake in resurrecting the 'Chimeras' decide to ally with the Americans for help in destroying the 'Chimeras'. The Americans and the Soviets then join forces to regroup and launch a final assault. After a few weeks of reconnaissance the Americans and Soviets discover that the 'Chimeras' fled to one of the Moons of Uranus, called Titania. And upon further orbital reconnaissance they find out that the 'Chimeras' are producing more 'Chimera' like beings. So, the Americans and Soviets then decide they must destroy the 'Chimeras' production factory and their Main Base, before the 'Chimeras' assault force can grow larger. But, the problem is the Main Base is located on Sycorax and whereas the Production Factory is located on Titonia. So, they are forced to divide their already smaller force into two smaller forces.  The Main Protagonist and his force are given the Task destroying the Production Factory in Titania while the other force assaults the Main 'Chimera' base in Sycorax. Also, it is shown that the Main Protagonist and all the other soldiers are shown to be really stressed out and worried. Because, they know that they are the only last line of defense. And at that moment they were the only force that was standing in between the 'Chimeras' and the  fate of the 'Universe'.

I saw the movie only till here. I missed the ending. I wish I could remember the name of the movie so that I can complete it.

Answer (score 10):

To start with, I have never watched a movie with this kind of a plot. But since, you've given a very long and detailed description, overcome by curiosity, I googled for the movie title. After some long browsing, I realized that what you are describing is not a movie at all, but a video game. This plot you've mentioned is exactly similar to the plot of the 1998 game **Battlezone**. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlezone_(1998_video_game)) is a link to the wikipedia page of the game from where you could read the entire plot of the game. But for your reference, here is the beginning of the game plot.

> Battlezone is set during the **1960s** with an **alternative history** plot, in which the Space Race is used to cover up the deployment of the United States and Soviet militaries into space. Both sides have used scraps of extraterrestrial "bio-metal", which have fallen to Earth as meteors, to build vehicles with amazing properties such as hover capability. Both nations deploy into space and are fighting across the solar system to control other deposits of the bio-metal. Gameplay is divided up into two campaigns; one following the American National Space Defense Force (NSDF), the other with the Soviet Cosmos Colonist Army (CCA, also referred to as the Communist Cosmonaut Army in early game manuals).
>
> The American campaign starts on the Moon, but the NSDF is forced off after the destruction of their main base. They relocate to Mars, but find the Soviets already there. Both sides locate alien artifacts, and the Americans also find a factory; the long-dead alien race that created the bio-metal is identified as the Cthonians, who inhabited the planet Icarus (now the asteroid belt) and visited Earth on several occasions, influencing Greek mythology. The Americans learn of an ultimate weapon called the "Fury" and head to Venus to learn more about it. Another Cthonian relic is recovered, pointing to Jupiter's moon Io. The NSDF finds a third relic, but this is stolen by a scientist defecting to the Soviets. The player must steal a Soviet fighter craft and tap into the communications network, which reveals the CCA relocation to their main base on Saturn's moon Titan. The Americans clear nearby Europa of CCA units to prevent early warning to those on Titan, but the main assault is annihilated, as the Soviets have begun to manufacture Fury vehicles. However, the Furies turn on the Soviets; they are self-aware and programmed to destroy all life. Icarus was destroyed by the Cthonians to prevent the Furies from reaching Earth. The NSDF and CCA ally against the new threat, and after destroying the production factory on Titan, travel to the fictional moon of Achilles, orbiting Uranus. The Americans destroy the main Fury base, but this causes the moon's core to destabilise, and the player must destroy the Furies' evacuation vessel before it escapes, then escape themselves.

You can read the rest of the plot from the wikipedia page to which I gave the link above. The plot, including the names of the moons and races is just as you described. The only difference I noted was that the name of the ultimate weapon is changed to `Fury` in the game whereas you mentioned it to be `Chimera`.

It's amazing that you could remember such a vivid amount of details, including the names of races and weapons and yet not recall it to be a game. Could it be that you read the description from somewhere or watched someone play the game and you later remembering only the content, led to believe that it was a movie? Now, I'm sorry if there is a movie with the same plot, made from the game or vice versa, but I however was not able to find any after an extensive google search. Hopefully, this answers your question.

Comment: Congratulations, this is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1795/49).